# Radio group labelling and semantics

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

I can't seem to get `fieldset`'s to react properly when using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` even if I reset the default values, it just reacts oddly in a variety of ways in different browsers/devices, so as a result I have actually removed all `fieldset`'s and replaced them with `div`'s.

Is this a semantically accurate method to label a radio group? or is there a better more semantic method aside from using `fieldset`/`legend`?

```html
<form method="get" novalidate>
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell label">

      <label for="r1-group">Pet Type</label>

    </div>
    <div class="table-cell input">
      <div id="r1-group" class="table-row radio-group neg41">
        <div class="table-cell">

          <input id="r3" name="same2" type="radio" />
          <label for="r3" class="radio-label">Cat</label>

        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">

          <input id="r4" name="same2" type="radio" />
          <label for="r4" class="radio-label">Dog</label>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</form>
```

I've always approached it in this manner, but to avoid using flexbox and floats I used the above instead.

```html
<form method="get" novalidate>
<fieldset class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell label">

      <legend for="r1-group">Pet Type</legend>

    </div>
    <div class="table-cell input">
      <div id="r1-group" class="table-row radio-group">
        <div class="table-cell">

          <input id="r3" name="same2" type="radio" />
          <label for="r3" class="radio-label">Cat</label>

        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">

          <input id="r4" name="same2" type="radio" />
          <label for="r4" class="radio-label">Dog</label>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Should I be bolstering this with Schema's microdata and aria to improve semantics instead?

Comment: Why is this tagged CSS when there is no CSS here?  Also tagged as HTML5 when there are no new HTML5 elements.

Comment: The CSS is listed encase someone perhaps knows a work around to the CSS oddities with fieldset, and similarly if there are html5 elements that aren't being used that may fit this situation better.

Comment: The complaint about rendering sounds like a Stack Overflow question. If you want to use a `fieldset`, but you can't get it to render the way you want, ask on SO, stating what your expected rendering is, how the actual result differs, what browsers you have tested.

Comment: On the other hand, the semantic judgement question is still on-topic on Code Review. I think that `fieldset` is probably overkill for a single radio choice.

Comment: @200_success yup, that was my thought, hence why I didn't ask about CSS question, just mentioned it as a reason this situation came to light, and tagged encase someone wanted to add input.

Comment: Class names such as `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell` etc. are semantically very bad. Classes should represent the function if the elements, not their look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use the [`label` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-label-element) like that. Its [`for` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#attr-label-for) may only refer to "[labelable elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#category-label)" (and `div` isn’t labelable).

#### Semantic markup

(Assuming that you can’t use `fieldset`.)

You can ignore all the `div` elements (except their "meaningful" attributes, if any), because they are meaningless. So your markup is essentially this:

```html
<form method="get" novalidate>

  <label>Pet Type</label>

  <input id="r3" name="same2" type="radio" />
  <label for="r3">Cat</label>

  <input id="r4" name="same2" type="radio" />
  <label for="r4">Dog</label>

</form>
```

Having a `label` without associated form control is not wrong, but maybe uncommon. It "represents a caption in a user interface", so I guess you could keep it like that.

If you want more "structure", you could use the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element). However, I think it might be overkill for such a simple case.

#### Accessibility

WAI-ARIA [recommends](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/roles#radio) "that elements with role `radio` are explicitly grouped in order to indicate which ones affect the same value".

(In HTML5, `input` elements in the [radio button state](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#radio-button-state-%28type=radio%29) have the `radio` role by default.)

How to group them explicitly?

> This is achieved by enclosing the radio elements in an element with role `radiogroup`.

So you should use the [`radiogroup` role](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/roles#radiogroup), e.g.:

```html
<form method="get" novalidate>

  <div role="radiogroup">
    <label>Pet Type</label>

    <input id="r3" name="same2" type="radio" />
    <label for="r3">Cat</label>

    <input id="r4" name="same2" type="radio" />
    <label for="r4">Dog</label>
  </div>

</form>
```

(HTML5 recommends *not* to set `role="radio"` for the radio buttons explicitly, but you *may* do so if you want to.)

Comment: Thanks, these links and your answer really helped me sort through the things I was unsure on. Great answer!